# sparkSQL Postgres / DateDiff is not coverting to date

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, redash

//*DateDiff does not work in redash postgres SQl.  Redash are auto foramtted to dd/mm/yyyy by default.  How would I use to_char(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') in this scenerio *//

--CASE WHEN actual_config_higher_assy.inst_DT_TM > cast('2046-12-31 06:28:13.000000' as timestamp(6)) THEN NULL ELSE cast(actual_config_higher_assy.inst_DT_TM as date) END,
DATEDIFF(day, '1900-01-01T00:00:00', remis_restricted.actchb_xlt_vw.install_date)+2 AS WING_INST_DT
remis_restricted.actchb_xlt_vw.remove_date

```
When I run this part in my statement, the results come out as a string. Column Wing_INST_DT Results 37,714.

I'm trying to covert it to date.
```

Comment: I can't find documentation for the `datediff` function anywhere in PostgreSQL. It seems to be an SQL Server function.

Comment: to calculate the difference between 2 dates or timestamps, just use `-`. Something like this: `SELECT '2046-12-31 06:28:13'::timestamp - '1900-01-01T00:00:00'::timestamp;` The result will be an interval